# Which module should I use for Python collection type hints: collections.abc or typing?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I am unclear on whether to use `typing` or `ABC` classes for collection type hints in Python. It seems one can use either one, but the name `typing` suggests that's the preferred one. However, I see several places saying `collections.abc` should be used instead, not least [PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/).

I am getting the sense that `typing` was created to support generics but that generics is being extended to the "regular" classes so `typing` is becoming obsolete. Is that the correct understanding?

Comment: Since that PEP585 you mentioned says *"... Importing those from typing is deprecated"* - feels like they're separating generic from typing?

Comment: Is there anything beyond the name `typing` that's confusing you?

Comment: @joel, I guess I got the impression that `collections.abc` were meant to be used as abstract base classes, which sounds like a distinctly different usage from typing. But of course if you are deriving classes from these base classes, it stands to reason to do typing with them as opposed to using some other parallel hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. `collections.abc` is the correct module going forward. Collections in `typing` have been [deprecated since 3.9](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/)